# How do I convert imported css attribute to line styling?

Tags: css, reactjs

Some style attributes are defined under `.slick-slide` in `carousel.css` like this.

```
//carousel.css
.slick-slide {
    padding-right: 16px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
 }
```

and `carousel.css` is imported and applied to `<Slider/>` In this case, how do I convert it to inline style?

```
import Slider from "react-slick";
import "../css/carousel.css";
const Carousel = ({content}) => {
    (...)
    return (
    <div>
      <Slider {...settings}>
        {content}
      </Slider>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Convert what actually to jsx format?

Comment: your question is not clear, but i think this will help
 
https://scotch.io/tutorials/converting-css-in-react-to-styled-component